# Android Development In Eclipse - Button Doesn't Show Text As Referenced

Tags: android

i have created two buttons and a textbox. the textbox shows the text that i referenced but the buttons don't show the text as referenced. Instead they show "button". Also when i run the application on my emulator then the application stops. Please Help!

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Disp"
        tools:context=".myMain"
        android:textSize= "45dp"
         />

    <button
        android:id="@+id/bAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="45dp" />

    <button
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/bSub"
        android:textSize = "45dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the Strings.xml

```
<resources> 
<string name="app_name">Basictut</string> 
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
 <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
 <string name="title_activity_my_main">myMain</string>
 <string name="Disp">Your Total Is 0</string>
 <string name="add">Add one</string>
 <string name="sub">Subtract one</string>
 </resources>
```

Java Code is:

```
package com.example.basictut;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class myMain extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_my_main, menu);
         return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: can you post your Strings.xml?

Comment: Also, when you say it stops on the emulator, do you mean *only* on the emulator? Could you post the log cat too?

Comment: Also, make sure (for the text problem) that you're not setting the text of the button in java code.

Comment: Here is the Strings.xml <resources>

    <string name="app_name">Basictut</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_my_main">myMain</string>
    <string name="Disp">Your Total Is 0</string>
    <string name="add">Add one</string>
    <string name="sub">Subtract one</string>

</resources>

Comment: It stops only on the emulator because that is the only thing i am using to test my application sir

Comment: ok. it seems as @Kgrover posted that you are setting text from your java code. Post your java code. and the error logcat in the question.

Comment: that layout file looks truncated - does it have a closing tag for the LinearLayout?

Comment: Also, how do you know what the buttons show if your application stops in the emulator? Are you talking about the xml graphical preview, or is it actually "button" when you run the application (but then, when does it stop)?

Comment: That's all the xml i copied and pasted

Comment: In graphical preview i see 'button' and in emulator it gives error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml is case sensitive, I think you should write `Button` instead of `button`.

Comment: Thankyou Man!. So Foolish Of Me To Not Notice A Silly Mistake. Next Time Going To Trust The Intellisense